# Job fetching data from JPA returns empty list

Tags: java, spring, jpa, quartz

I have a confusing problem with fetching data from JPA during Job processing - Postgresql

Repository extends JpaRepository:

```
@QueryHints(value = @QueryHint(name = HINT_FETCH_SIZE, value = "1"))
Stream<Object> findAll(Specification specification);
```

Service:

```
@Scheduled(cron = "0 0/1 * * * ?")
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
public void runTask() {
    try(myRepository.findAll(spec)) {}
}
```

It's a bit strange because it works on my local machine, but when I publish an application on the environment with 3 instances. As a result, I have an empty stream.

The problem doesn't occur when I create a Rest controller with will trigger this method.

Comment: did you check whether the data presents all kinds of environments or not?

Comment: @JoonseoLee yes, the weird thing is that I can receive this data on the Env when I use an HTTP request via rest controller. In the beginning, I thought that I have a problem with Transaction, but right now those Env instances are my biggest suspicious. There are triggered almost at the same time.

Comment: then you could see the env text in profile.active while running spring boot. and those are different each env?

Comment: @JoonseoLee of course there are different but when we talk about data source configuration and scheduled is almost similar.

Comment: I've checked the database again and the problem was different databases on each instance and the problem with the task scheduler on correct instances caused by Thread pooling. Thanks @JoonseoLee